# Run Main class In visual studio 2010 from command line

Tags: visual-studio, command-line

I have a main class in C# and I'm trying to run this class from command line. 
is it possible or i need to use the Visual studio command line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you compile the project to an EXE, you can run the EXE like any other EXE.

Unlike Java, there is no concept of executing a specific class in .Net; running a managed EXE file will execute that assembly's entry point (`Main()` method).